# How do I cancel a dynamic event in Anylogic?

Tags: events, anylogic

I have a model that uses dynamic events to schedule a change in the size of a resource pool based on [Stuart's response this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051127/model-start-and-end-values-for-schedule-as-a-variable)
For my application I want the model user to be able to cancel the upcoming Dynamic event by clicking a button as part of the UI but I am not sure how to implement this using the [reset() function](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/statecharts/dynamic-event.html#:%7E:text=DESCRIPTION-,void%20reset(),-Discards%20the%20scheduled).
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to save the instance of the dynamic event:

so let's imagine your dynamic event is called Dynamic
you can trigger it with `create_Dynamic();`

Create a variable of type Dynamic... let's call this variable x
and then do

```
x=create_Dynamic();
```

with this you can just cancel the dynamic event by doing

```
x.reset();
```

But the point of using dynamic events is that every time you do create_Dynamic() an instance of this event is created that is used independently so you shouldn't need to cancel it.

If you need to cancel an event, instead use a normal even triggered by user... then you can cancel it easily

Answer (score 0):

Felipe has the better answer. But you could also simply add an `if` check into your dynamic event. Whenever it triggers, it actually only does stuff when the user did not cancel things:

```
if (userCancelledByNow) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    your normal DE logic code
}
```

(If users click a button, you need to save that as a boolean variable somewhere to check in the dynamic event above)