# AnyLogic - dynamic schedule for resourcePool cast from Integer to TimeUnits

Tags: casting, simulation, anylogic

I refer to the following [SOW post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051127/model-start-and-end-values-for-schedule-as-a-variable) and the answer of Stuart Rossiter.

I thought it was right to open a new thread about this, as the problem can be looked at a little differently after all these years. Now I get the following error: "The method create_ShiftChange(double, TimeUnits) in the Main type is not applicable for the arguments (int, Integer)."

As I noted in my comment from Stuart Rossiter's solution, I believe the function `create_ShiftChange(...)` had different input arguments a few years ago.

The cast from `getTimeoutToNextValue()` to `double` is not a problem. However, the cast of the second argument `getNextValue()` from `Integer` to `TimeUnits` presents me with a challenge.

Does anyone have a solution for my problem or do I have to look for a detour, since the "old" `create_ShiftChange(...)` also has a different meaning due to the other input arguments? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There hasn't been a change in the `create_*` functions (methods) for dynamic events. There are two forms:

- One where you explicitly specify the time units for when it should be scheduled (so with 2 initial arguments of type `double` and `TimeUnits`). `TimeUnits` is a Java enum (effectively what an AnyLogic option list is under the covers) with values like `TimeUnits.MINUTE`; auto-complete will show you the alternatives.
- One where you implicitly assume the time units of the model as a whole, as in its properties (so with 1 initial argument of type `double`).

The dynamic event in question has a single `int` argument (i.e., its 'event-specific' data comprises just an integer), so the relevant `create_*` function variants have this as their final argument (i.e., they have 3 and 2 arguments respectively).

In your case, you are **not** using a dynamic event with a single argument (otherwise the method `create_ShiftChange(double, TimeUnits)` it's complaining about wouldn't exist — it would be `create_ShiftChange(double, TimeUnits, int)` instead) and, since you've called it with two integers, the compiler (incorrectly) assumes you were trying to use the 2 argument form, hence the error message.

So either add the argument to the dynamic event or, if in your case you're using a different set of arguments (or no arguments) for your dynamic event, change accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to type `TimeUnits.` (note the dot!) and then use code-complete. This shows you all the options you have available, choose the one you need.
[image]

Background: This is an enum defined by AnyLogic to be used for time units. When you see things like that, always type it out and try code-complete

Comment: This is not the (main) problem; look at the other question and the method signatures in question.